# Is there any way to record and play mouse click in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, automation

I'm trying to record a jsx using Photoshop scriptlistener plugin. Is there any way by which I can record the mouse click and play it again using scripting? I'm using the latest version of Photoshop.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve with that?

Comment: If you want to record your screen including your cursor, PS is not the right tool. Look for screen recording software and maybe an extra mouse highlight tool that visualizes clicks like Mouseposé.

Comment: @Joonas I want to record coordinates of mouse click relative to the image so that i can perform various operation at that particular point using scripting. Some of these operations are quick selection, brush stroke, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I Believe you are referencing to something that photoshop already does, This is what's known as an action. If you record an action, you will notice that it should also record the mouse clicks too. I hope this helps you.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can help with.

Comment: I tried it and though it's not exactly what I need but  it somewhat solves my purpose. My requirement is to capture mouse click on a point on image so that I can use it with any tool to click again on the same point. With actions, I can record a click but it also captures the tool being used, so when I play the action again, same tool is used again. My requirement is that it should play the click with currently selected tool. Hope you can help me with that too.